# Adding additional methods to custom permissions evaluator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a customs permissions evaluator setup something like the following.

```
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object target, Object permission) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Then in my Configuration I have

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MyPermissionEvaluator myPermissionEvaluator;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        methodSecurityExpressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(myPermissionEvaluator);
        return methodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }
```

This works fine for the standard use cases when using "hasPermission" on preAuth on my methods security for example

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#model.appName, 'RETRIVE')")
```

However I now need to add a custom method to check something else and hasPermission isn't enough for me, I need to have my own custom method so I tried adding it into the current permissions evaluator

```
public boolean myNewMethod(String app) {
        // do something
    }
```

Then on my method signature I updated the preAuth to have

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#model.appName, 'RETRIVE') or myNewMethod(#model.value)")
```

this gives the following error ***"org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasRoleAndStoreFor(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot"***

I then tried updating the preAuth to

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#model.appName, 'RETRIVE') or @myPermissionEvaluator.myNewMethod(#model.value)")
```

and this gives me the following error

***No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'myPermissionEvaluator***

I then tried moving the method out to a new service and doing

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#model.appName, 'RETRIVE') or @newService.myNewMethod(#model.value)")
```

but no luck.

Any ideas? I am lost how to make this work

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the method static, use

`T(com.foo.MyClass).myNewMethod(#model.value)`

Comment: @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#model.appName, 'RETRIVE') or T(com.foo.MyClass).myNewMethod(#model.value)") ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that worked for me.

1. Implement the root note where the evaluation of all security expressions starts. Add you custom method in this class.

   ```
    public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    private Authentication auth;

    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot( Authentication authentication) {
      super(authentication);
      this.auth=authentication;

    }

    // Your custom method
    public boolean myNewMethod(String app) {
     // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
    }

   }
   ```
2. Inject the **CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot** in **CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler** class which extends **DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler**.

   ```
    public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Override
    public MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot( Authentication authentication,
            MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        return root;
    }

     @Override
     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
            super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

     }
   }
   ```
3. Next use **CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler** in the method security configuration.

   ```
    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = 
          new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

   }
   ```
4. Now you are all set to use your custom method in controller.

   ```
   @PreAuthorize("myNewMethod(#model.value)")
   ```

Furthermore, If you need any service to autowire in **CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot** class, you have to do this by using setter.

```
private UserService userService;


private PostService postService;

public void setUserService(UserService userService){
  this.userService = userService;
}
public void setPostService(PostService postService) {
  this.postService = postService;
}
```

And you need to call this setters in **CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler** class.

```
root.setUserService(applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class));
root.setPostService(applicationContext.getBean(PostService.class));
```